# Why removing one line over two in 2D frequency domain give me a repetition artifacts?

Tags: python, fft, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand why if I set to 0+0j one line over two on the bottom half of the frequency domain gives me a shifted copy on the original image when I reconstruct the spacial image:

[image]

here is the example

```
import cv2 as cv
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imgpath =  "MRI_blackandwhite.png"
img = cv.imread(imgpath, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
norm_image = cv.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_32F)
amp = (np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(norm_image)))
amp[367//2:-1:2] = amp[367//2:-1:2]* (0+0j)
amp_log =  np.abs(amp)
norm_amp = cv.normalize(amp_log, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_32F)
restoredAMP = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(amp)))

plt.subplot(131), plt.imshow(norm_image, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1), plt.title('Image')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(132), plt.imshow(norm_amp, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1), plt.title('Amplitude')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(133), plt.imshow(restoredAMP, "gray", vmin=0, vmax=1), plt.title('Restored ')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

and the image:
[image]

Comment: You take the absolute value (magnitude) of the inverse transform. This is problematic because it hides wrong manipulation in the frequency domain. If you expect a real-valued spatial domain signal, then take the real component of the inverse transform, and verify that the imaginary component is indeed zero (up to rounding errors). That verification is of course only needed during development, but is a good way to spot errors in your logic.

Comment: In the reconstruction, i take amp which are complex values.

Comment: You do `restoredAMP = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(amp)))`, this should be `restoredAMP = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(amp))`, then check that `restoredAMP.imag` is nearly zero, then use `restoredAMP.real` as your output.

Comment: That is not modifying the "copy" effect that I see.

Comment: No, but it should show you’re doing something wrong, because your imaginary component is not close to zero. It should be as large as the real part. I’m not posting an answer, just a comment about how you can improve your code and your thinking to help you find what the problem is.

Comment: To have a real-valued spatial domain, your frequency domain must have complex-conjugate symmetry. If you modify frequency component A, you also have to modify frequency component -A, in such a way that the two components are each other’s complex conjugate. Because you are not maintaining this symmetry, your inverse transform is not real-valued, you have a non-zero imaginary component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is that you are multiplying half of your k-space by a delta comb filter. Here some pseudo-code

```
delta_comb = np.ones(shape)
delta_comb[shape//2:-1:2] = 0
k_space_ = k_space * delta_comb
ifft(k_space_) = ifft(k_space) convolved with ifft(delta_comb)

# and
ifft(delta_comb) = delta_comb_with_1_over_spacing
```

Multiplication in k-space is equivalent to convolution by the FFT(delta comb) in image space. The FFT of a delta comb is another delta comb, with spacing FOV/k-spacing. In your case k-spacing=2, so the FFT of the delta comb is a delta comb with FOV/2 spacing.
If you convolve your image with a delta comb, you get copies of your image centered at each individual delta.

The fact that you are taking only half of your k-space just messes up with the relative amplitudes of the image and its "N/2 ghost", but it would work just the same if you had  `amp[0:-1:2] = amp[0:-1:2]* (0+0j)` in there instead.

But why? What is the intuition behind this, you may ask. Well, by zeroing out lines of k-space you are forcing the coefficients of a number of waves to necessary be zero. Since the coefficient of any given point in k-space is defined by a sum over components in the dual space (image space), the only way for a component to be 0 is if this sum perfectly cancels out.
Because frequencies are independent from each other, the only way for coefficients to cancel out is if the positive and negative wave perfectly cancel each out, which means they have to be perfectly out of phase. For that you need them to be shifted.
So it's really about the phase being zero that causes the information from the opposing wave to not be cancelled or be cancelled out. You cannot reason about it thinking of amplitudes alone.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how some optimization works in MRI recording, like record only half the kspace an still be able to reconstruct the image. So basically, yo can use the recording of the other half to complete the missing recorded voxel in kspace.

Comment: Not always because there are always phase errors in the k-space lines, so you can't simply acquire just half of k-space (because you can't perfectly estimate what the phase of the other half looks like). See https://mriquestions.com/partial-fourier.html and the references therein, especially the intro of the MacFall et al paper and the conclusion of the McGibney et al paper

Comment: The website you gave is handsome. It gives important information on how MRI works. Thanks so much for that.